# Getting erc20 contract holders

Tags: ether

I'm developing a Python script to calculate the amount of holders of an erc20 contract token. To do so, I have 2 sqlite tables. One to save the transactions from block X1 to block X2, and the other one to do some math and save the pair wallet-amount of tokens. Finally I get the wallets with more than X tokens and that's the holders number.

But here's the problem: the number I get is different than Etherscan.

I think I'm doing something wrong. And I have a doubt: Every time I read a transaction where "from" wallet is not inserted in my table, i'm inserting it with value/amount 0. And every time I read a transaction where "to" wallet is not inserted in my table, i'm inserting it with value/amount = 'amount of the transaction'.

My doubt: is correct to insert 0 in "from" wallet at first time ? And is correct to insert the amount of the transaction in "to" wallet at first time ? Or I have to get the balance of these wallets on these blocks and then add or substract taking into account this number ? I tried to do it but it doesn't work, the number of holders is even worse than before.

Obviously if "from" and/or "to" wallet exists in my table the solution is easy: add or subtract the "amount" of the transaction. But my doubt is related to the first time I have to insert them...

Thanks.